# jQuery not getting all the elements sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I have a somewhat weird problem. I created a chrome extension that will automatically scroll down as users edit a google document. It seems to be working okay when the doc is in paginated mode. If I switch it to compact mode, then it seems like jQuery won't get all the requested elements. The basic HTML tree is pretty much the same in paginated and compact modes. I'm stumped and not sure why it's not working correctly. We should be looking mostly at how '$currentPage' works. Sometimes the height returns 0 when it shouldn't happen.

**[EDIT] Here's when it'll mess up:** It works fine in paginated mode. But when I start the extension in compact mode when there are text already on page 2, it'll work as expected. If I delete texts all the way back to page 1, it'll still work as expected. But if I start typing text back into page 2, it'll start to mess up.

Here's the code:

```
function autoScrollFunc(){
   if(autoscrollEnabled){
      var oldCount = pageCount;
      // get all the pages
      var $pages = $("div.kix-page");
      // count how many pages there are
      pageCount = $pages.length;
      console.dir($pages);
      console.dir($pages.last());
      console.dir($pages.last().find("div.kix-paragraphrenderer"));
      $currentPage = $pages.last().find("div.kix-paragraphrenderer").first();
      //console.dir($currentPage);
      //pageHeight = $pages.first().height();
      if(pageCount != oldCount){
         // update data if there are changes in page count
         console.log("Number of pages changed! Count: " + pageCount);
         pageHeight = $pages.first().height();
      }
      // scroll to new position
      scrollToNewPosition();
   }
}

function scrollToNewPosition(){
   if(autoscrollEnabled){
      oldHeight = viewLoc;
      var upperSection = toolbarHeight + getRulerHeight();
      var windowHeight = $(window).height();
      var marginHeight = (pageCount > 1) ? getTopMarginHeight() : firstMarginHeight;
      var docViewHeight = (windowHeight > upperSection) ? (windowHeight - upperSection) : 0;

      // calculate the scroll location
      var totalDocHeight = (pageHeight * (pageCount-1)) + $currentPage.height() + marginHeight;
      viewLoc = (totalDocHeight < docViewHeight) ? 0 : totalDocHeight - docViewHeight + $currentPage.height();

      console.log("upperSection: %s, windowHeight: %s, marginHeight: %s, docViewHeight: %s, totalDocHeight: %s, viewLoc: %s, currentPage.height(): %s",
            upperSection, windowHeight, marginHeight, docViewHeight, totalDocHeight, viewLoc, $currentPage.height());

      if(oldHeight != viewLoc){
         // if there are changes in height, then scroll to the new position
         $docScroller.animate({ scrollTop: viewLoc}, 250);
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to try the extension yourself, here's the project URL:

http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-autoscroll/

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Can you verify that the DOM elements are still on the page. At times, it is possible that the DOM node you have cached, has been replaced. So you need to purge and re-create your cache.

Comment: Yeah, the DOM elements are still on the page. The timer will repeatedly call autoScrollFunc(), wouldn't that recreate the new caches every time it gets polled?

Comment: can u try using outerHeight instead of height for $currentPage?

Comment: Hello Amit. Thank you so much for helping me out. Unfortunately, changing from height() to outerHeight() doesn't change anything. I added a scenario where it'll mess up in the post.

Comment: Can you verify that $currentPage is actually refering to the current element when the height is returned as zero?